# If the group if abelian, must all automorphisms be outer automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am having some thought about this question.

Clearly, if the group $G$ is abelian, then $\mathrm{Inn}(G) = {e}$.  But what about $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\mathrm{Out}(G) = \mathrm{Aut}(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(G)$?  Must $\mathrm{Aut}(G) = \mathrm{Out}(G)$?  Take $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ as the example.  We know that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ consists of 6 bijective functions.  Must $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ also consist of 6 bijective functions?

Different example:

$G = D_4$

$G$ is not abelian and noncyclic.  It consists of $4$ elements in $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ and $8$ elements in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.  Must $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ consist of 2 elements?  I found that there are 4 functions instead of 2.

Comment: If $G$ is any group then $G$ is isomorphic to $G/\{1\}$.

Comment: You have answered your own question.  Since $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong e$, it follows that $\operatorname{Out}(G)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(G)/\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: @Jared What about nonabelian group like $D_4$?

Answer (score 4):

Can you see that you have correctly answered your question?

For abelian group $G$, we know $\,\operatorname{Inn}(G) \cong e.\;$ So, we have that $$\operatorname{Out}(G)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(G)/\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(G)$$

Comment: Yup!  Another question: What if $G$ is nonabelian, say $D_4$?  How would $Out(D_4)$ look like?

Comment: @NasuSama, please ask a new question. Asking about non-abelian groups is a question whose title clearly states that it is about abelian groups is not a great idea!

Comment: @NasuSama: [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395999/find-mathrmautg-mathrminng-and-mathrmautg-mathrminng?rq=1) might clear up confusion about $D_4$

Comment: Nice work Amy +

Comment: NasuSama: did this help at all? (Nice answer, btw, (+1) on the rational root theorem!)