# Suppose that $G$ is nonabelian. Must $|\mathrm{Out}(G)| = |\mathrm{Aut}(G)|/|\mathrm{Inn}(G)|$?

Tags: group-theory

I would say not.  Suppose that $G = D_4$.  By the [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Conjugacy_classes_of_reflections) I found, $D_4$ has 4 outer automorphisms.  I understand how reflection comes to play, but $|\mathrm{Out}(G)| \neq |\mathrm{Aut}(G)|/|\mathrm{Inn}(G)|$.  Is this true?

Comment: You've already noted in a [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398417/if-the-group-if-abelian-must-all-automorphisms-be-outer-automorphisms) the isomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(G)/\operatorname{Inn}(G)=\operatorname{Out}(G)$.  If $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is finite, your result follows from [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)).

Comment: How could this not be the case? The outer automorphisms are precisely the quotient by the inner ones

Comment: ${\rm Out}(G)={\rm Aut}(G)/{\rm Inn}(G)$ is always true. What makes you think that $|{\rm Out}(G)|$ does not equal $|{\rm Aut}(G)|/|{\rm Inn}(G)|$ in the case of $G=D_4$?

Comment: This earlier post might help clarify things for you, if you're confused by your computations: [Inner and Outer automorphisms of $D_4$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395999/find-mathrmautg-mathrminng-and-mathrmautg-mathrminng?rq=1)

Comment: What is your definition of $\operatorname{Out}(G)$?

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{Out}(G)$ is defined as the quotient $\operatorname{Aut}(G)/\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, so $$\left|\operatorname{Out}(G)\right|=\left[\operatorname{Aut}(G):\operatorname{Inn}(G)\right]=\frac{\left|\operatorname{Aut}(G)\right|}{\left|\operatorname{Inn}(G)\right|}$$ no matter what $G$ is.  Your confusion seems to be that you think that $\operatorname{Out}(G)$ denotes the *set* of otuer automorphisms of $G$, which is not true.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the count of outer automorphisms $\{ \alpha \in \operatorname{Aut}(G) : \alpha \text{ is outer } \} = \operatorname{Aut}(G) - \operatorname{Inn}(G)$ has size $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)| - |\operatorname{Inn}(G)|$